# Configure sudo for UserA to run commands as UserB (not root)

Tags: command-line, server, sudo, password, visudo

I have some automated tools that need to be able to run as a specific user. The username is "ig_root" and it is only used by a monitoring tool (checks disk space, database, CPU workload, etc) that sends us warnings when something may need human intervention.

What we need to be able to do is to issue a sudo command to run things as the ig_root user. I have my "invadm" account that is a member of sudo group, and it can "sudo su - root", but it prompts for a password. What I need to set up is to be able to do something similar for a non-root user but that does NOT prompt for the password.

In other words, as "invadm" user we want to do this:

```
# sudo -u ig_root check_dbspace
```

...without seeing this:

```
[sudo] password for invadm:
```

But I also want conecting to root to still require the password entry for everyone:

```
# sudo su - root
[sudo] password for invadm:
```

Is that possible?

My current visudo entries look like this on my test server:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
invadm  ALL=(ig_root) NOPASSWD: ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Any ideas as to what I'm missing? I thought maybe I have to issue the systemctl and stop/restart something, but I learned that there is no sudo daemon to restart. I also tried logging out and back in to pick up any new environment... no luck.

Right now, the only account that sudo does not ask for a password is when I'm root user.

```
# sudo -u ig_root whoami
ig_root
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this is Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when several entries match for the same user, the last match is used. Since `invadm` is in group sudo the `%sudo` entry applies, hence the request for a password.

Simply move your specific rules to the end of the file.

Comment: Dang! You are exactly right. Taking the exact same "invadm" line, I moved that to the bottom of the sudoers file and now invadm user is NOT prompted for a password when trying to run things as ig_root user. Thanks so much for this. I was under the impression each section was similar to the stanzas in some config files, and that I needed my entry under the "User privilege specs" section.

Comment: No, there is no structure to the sudoers file. `sudo -ll` can show you what it thinks you can do, but I don't know if it would provide any clues in this sort of case.